# "Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow" when save image to database

Tags: android

I am making an application to save images. There is no problem when adding an image from the application's camera and the gallery image. But when I added a photo directly from the phone camera, it was not possible.

Error "Couldn't read row 0, col 0 from CursorWindow.  Make sure the Cursor is initialized correctly before accessing data from it." encountered in the code line "int id = cursor.getInt (0);" of MainActivity java class.

How to solve ?

My code is below.

**MainActivity class**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

Button buttonAddItem;
public static Database database;
ListView listViewItem;
ArrayList<Item> itemArrayList;
ItemAdapter itemAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    buttonAddItem = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAddItem);
    listViewItem = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewItem);

    // Set ListView
    itemArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
    itemAdapter = new ItemAdapter(this, R.layout.line_item, itemArrayList);
    listViewItem.setAdapter(itemAdapter);

    // Create db and table
    database = new Database(this, "Manage.sqlite", null, 1);
    database.QueryData("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Item(Id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, Name VARCHAR(150)," +
            "Description VARCHAR(250), Image TEXT)");

    // Get all data to ListView
    Cursor cursor = database.GetData("SELECT * FROM Item");

    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        int id = cursor.getInt(0);
        String Name = cursor.getString(1);
        String Description = cursor.getString(2);
        String Image = cursor.getString(3);
        itemArrayList.add(new Item(id, Name, Description, Image));
    }
    itemAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    buttonAddItem.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            startActivity(new Intent(MainActivity.this, AddItemActivity.class));
        }
    });
}
}
```

**Database class**

```
public class Database extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

public Database(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

public void QueryData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    sqLiteDatabase.execSQL(sql);
}

public Cursor GetData(String sql) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getReadableDatabase();
    return sqLiteDatabase.rawQuery(sql, null);
}

public void Insert_Item(String name, String desciption, String image) {
    SQLiteDatabase sqLiteDatabase = getWritableDatabase();
    String sql = "INSERT INTO Item VALUES(null, ?, ?, ?)";
    SQLiteStatement sqLiteStatement = sqLiteDatabase.compileStatement(sql);
    sqLiteStatement.clearBindings();

    sqLiteStatement.bindString(1, name); // Begin index 0: id = null
    sqLiteStatement.bindString(2, desciption);
    sqLiteStatement.bindString(3, image);

    sqLiteStatement.executeInsert();
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

}
}
```

**AddItemActivity class**

```
public class AddItemActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText editTextName, editTextDescription;
ImageButton imageButtonCamera, imageButtonFolder;
ImageView imageViewImage;
Button buttonAdd, buttonCancel;

int REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA = 123;
int REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER = 456;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_add_item);

    Mapping();

    imageButtonCamera.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA);
        }
    });

    imageButtonFolder.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            intent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER);
        }
    });

    buttonAdd.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // Convert ImageView -> byte[]
            BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = (BitmapDrawable) imageViewImage.getDrawable();
            Bitmap bitmap = bitmapDrawable.getBitmap();
            ByteArrayOutputStream byteArray = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, byteArray);
            byte[] image = byteArray.toByteArray();
            String str = Base64.encodeToString(image, Base64.DEFAULT);

            // Insert Image to Database
            MainActivity.database.Insert_Item(editTextName.getText().toString().trim(),
                    editTextDescription.getText().toString().trim(), str);
            Toast.makeText(AddItemActivity.this, "Added.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(AddItemActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
        }
    });
}

// Get image and export to ImageView
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, @Nullable Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_CAMERA && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Bitmap bitmap = (Bitmap) data.getExtras().get("data");
        imageViewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_FOLDER && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
        Uri uri = data.getData();
        try {
            InputStream inputStream = getContentResolver().openInputStream(uri);
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(inputStream);
            imageViewImage.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

private void Mapping() {
    editTextName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextName);
    editTextDescription = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.editTextDescription);
    imageButtonCamera = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonCamera);
    imageButtonFolder = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.imageButtonFolder);
    imageViewImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageViewImage);
    buttonAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonAdd);
    buttonCancel = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonCancel);

    editTextName.requestFocus();
}
}
```

**ItemAdapter class**

```
public class ItemAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

private Context context;
private int layout;
List<Item> itemList;

public ItemAdapter(Context context, int layout, List<Item> itemList) {
    this.context = context;
    this.layout = layout;
    this.itemList = itemList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return itemList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int position) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int position) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    // Initialize view and mapping
    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        LayoutInflater layoutInflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = layoutInflater.inflate(layout, null);

        viewHolder.textViewName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewName);
        viewHolder.textViewDescription = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textViewDescription);
        viewHolder.imageViewLineItem = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageViewLineItem);

        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }

    // Set items
    Item item = itemList.get(position);

    viewHolder.textViewName.setText(item.getName());
    viewHolder.textViewDescription.setText(item.getDescription());
    // Convert byte[] -> bitmap
    try{
        byte[] image = Base64.decode(item.getImage(), Base64.DEFAULT);
        Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length);
        viewHolder.imageViewLineItem.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }


    return convertView;
}

private class ViewHolder {
    ImageView imageViewLineItem;
    TextView textViewName, textViewDescription;
}
}
```